# jquery call toggle event

Tags: jquery

I searched all over the net and didn't find solution

I need to disable click event on div, then write to file, then enable click event on div.

So, I have toggle event on div #method:

```
function openData(){
    $.post("writeFile", {'file':fileWrite})
     .done(function(data) {
         $('#method').on('click',*);
     });
}

$('#method').toggle(function(){
    $('#method').off('click');
    openData();
},function(){
    ... other similar stuff ...
});
```

I need to enable click on div #method .. this works: $('#method').on('click',callFunction); but i have to call some function, so I would like to call like $('#method').on('click',$('#method').toggle(function());

Is this possible?
Is it possible to just enable click on div #method like $('#method').on('click') and it works?

I will be very happy for any help.

Comment: I don't think so.. I think you have to attach the event handler again when you want to enable the click event.

Comment: in 1.9+ this form of toggle has been removed: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed

Comment: You might look at the `$.Deferred` stuff if you want to enable once the file write completes in the ajax. Here is a writeup example: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

Comment: Can't you just declare an extra boolean variable called inProgress or something of that sort and then add an if statement to make sure it does not write to the server till you are ready. Sounds like an overkill to bind and unbind events for that.

Comment: make sure that boolean variable is declared outside of your functions

Comment: I have that and it doesn't work. 1.click - function1, 2.click - nothing (waiting function1) 3.click - function1 4.click nothing (waiting function1) ... so you have multiple function1 and none function 2  and I need function2 for function1 (file read, file write, file show, file delete...)

Comment: Sorry for deleted post - couldn't edit any more. It is defined outside functions: var fileDeleted = 1; var fileWritten = 0;
$(document).ready(function() { ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I understand it. You probably also need to know the state of the toggle to do your write to file thing, and account for cases when ajax runs into errors, but here is a simple scoop (no extra bind/unbind is nessesary):

```
var inProgress = false;
$('#method').bind('click', function () {
    if (!inProgress) {
        inProgress = true;
        $('#method').toggle();
        openData();
    }
});

function openData(){
    $.post("writeFile", {'file':fileWrite})
        .done(function(data) {
            inProgress = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for 2 functions (openData and closeData) toggle. The second answer from @Félix works great.

Comment: ;) you mean you could not do: `if ($('#method').is(':visible')) {closeData();} else {openData();}` ? as i mentioned in the intro before answer "you probably need to know the state of the toggle to do your write thing". anyway, good luck!

Comment: I had to use if ($('#showData:visible').length > 0) and it works. Thank you very very much also :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but if you want your div toggle and do other stuff on finish, you can do:

```
var callFunction = function() {
    doStuff();
}
$('#method').on('click', function() {
    $('#method').toggle(callFunction);
}
```

Or using an anonymous function:

```
$('#method').on('click', function() {
    $('#method').toggle(function() {
        doStuff();
    });
}
```

So perhaps you want something like

```
var openData = function() {
    $('#method').off('click');
    $('#method').slideUp(function() {
        $.post("writeFile", {'file':fileWrite})
        .done(function() {
            $('#method').slideDown(function() {
                $('#method').on('click', openData);
            });
        });
    });
}

$('#method').on('click', openData);
```

I changed toggle for slideUp and slideDown because I think you don't really want to toggle after all, you want to hide while waiting and show while ready.

If you want to test it, I created a [jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/fAFsF/1/), using setTimeout to simulate an ajax delay.

Comment: this $('#method_'+i).on('click', open); works great but only for click not toggle and I really need toggle, because of:

default - div1->show, div_data->hidden
1. click (on div1): div_data->show ... get data (from file) into div, make temp file
2. click (on div1): div_data->hide ... delete temp file
3. click (on div1): div_data->show ... get data (from file) into div, make temp file
...

I probably need something like:
    $('#method_'+i).toggle(function(){
        $('#method_'+i).on('click', open);
    },function(){
        $('#method_'+i).on('click', close);
    });

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood what you want with toggle(). Perhaps this [modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fAFsF/2/) can help you.

Comment: This looks very promising. I will test it.